# Return from new Array creating table

Tags: javascript

I have an Array but I'm not able to display the result.
I don't know how can i fix it.

Someone know how can i fix it?

```js
function criarTabela(conteudo) {
  var tabela = document.createElement("table")
  var thead = document.createElement("thead")
  var tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
  var thd = function(i){return (i==0)?"th":"td";}
  for (var i=0;i<conteudo.length;i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr")
    for(var o=0;o<conteudo[i].length;o++){
      var t = document.createElement(thd(i))
      var texto=document.createTextNode(conteudo[i][o])
      t.appendChild(texto)
      tr.appendChild(t)
    }
    (i==0)?thead.appendChild(tr):tbody.appendChild(tr)
  }
  tabela.appendChild(thead)
  tabela.appendChild(tbody)
  return tabela
}
document.getElementById("consulta").appendChild(criarTabela(conteudo))
var conteudo = new Array google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(criarTabela).Alunos()
```

Return from Alunos()

```
['Data do Cadastro', 'Matricula', 'E-mail', 'Curso', 'OC', 'GN', 'P1', 'P2', 'Certificado'],
    [ '30/09/2021 14:11:12', '2021.02.34870', 'exemplo@terra.com.br', 'Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas', 3, 3, 1, 1, ''],
    [ '30/09/2021 18:52:12', '2021.02.95859', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '30/09/2021 18:58:22', '2021.02.29425', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Relacionamento e Vendas', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '30/09/2021 19:18:53', '2021.02.82395', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.54954', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.34870', 'exemplo@terra.com.br', 'Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas', 3, 3, 1, 1, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.95859', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.29425', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Relacionamento e Vendas', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.82395', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.34870', 'exemplo@terra.com.br', 'Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas', 3, 3, 1, 1, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.95859', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.29425', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Relacionamento e Vendas', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.82395', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.34870', 'exemplo@terra.com.br', 'Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas', 3, 3, 1, 1, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.95859', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.29425', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Relacionamento e Vendas', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.82395', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing', 0, 0, 0, 0, '']
```

Comment: *"I'm not able to display the result"*: that is a vague problem statement. Please describe what the problem is (error? hanging? wrong output?) and what the expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const arr = [['Data do Cadastro', 'Matricula', 'E-mail', 'Curso', 'OC', 'GN', 'P1', 'P2', 'Certificado'],
    [ '30/09/2021 14:11:12', '2021.02.34870', 'exemplo@terra.com.br', 'Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas', 3, 3, 1, 1, 'Si'],
    [ '30/09/2021 18:52:12', '2021.02.95859', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'No'],
    [ '30/09/2021 18:58:22', '2021.02.29425', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Relacionamento e Vendas', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '30/09/2021 19:18:53', '2021.02.82395', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.54954', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.34870', 'exemplo@terra.com.br', 'Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas', 3, 3, 1, 1, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.95859', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.29425', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Relacionamento e Vendas', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.82395', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.34870', 'exemplo@terra.com.br', 'Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas', 3, 3, 1, 1, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.95859', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.29425', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Relacionamento e Vendas', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.82395', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.34870', 'exemplo@terra.com.br', 'Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas', 3, 3, 1, 1, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.95859', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Marketing Digital', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.29425', 'exemplo@yahoo.com.br', 'Relacionamento e Vendas', 0, 0, 0, 0, ''],
    [ '04/10/2021 14:28:56', '2021.02.82395', 'exemplo@hotmail.com.br', 'Marketing', 0, 0, 0, 0, '']]
    
document.getElementById("thead").innerHTML = 
`<tr>
  ${arr[0].map(item => `<th>${item}</th>`)
  .join("")}
<tr>`;
document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = 
  arr.slice(1).map(item => `<tr>
    ${item.map(cell => `<td>${cell}</td>`).join("")}
  </tr>`).join("");
```

```css
#myTable tr:nth-child(odd) { 
      background-color:  #fff;  
 }
#myTable tr:nth-child(even) { 
      background-color:  #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<thead id="thead"></thead>
<tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```